# Is it possible to get device load in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I know how to use `clGetDeviceInfo` to query information about the device but I don't know how to get information about the device at runtime. For example, how much global memory is in use right now? How busy have the processing elements been, on average, in the last n nanoseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, no. OpenCL itself does not have any API to query current status of a device. Those are exposed by the vendor of your particular implementation (like the [GPUPerfAPI](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/gpuperfapi/) from AMD or the [Graphics Performance analyzer](http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/intel-gpa) from Intel).

Hope this helps.

Comment: There seems to be only one thing about the device you can query in OpenCl, is whether it is "available" or not. I am not sure how relevant this state is for current hardware, though.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to be able to determine the free memory at runtime is write a wrapper around clDevice (or cl::Device in my case) and pipe all buffer allocations through said wrapper.

At the begin of the program, I query the total device memory (`CL_DEVICE__GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE`) and when buffers are allocated I store their addresses and sizes in a vector so I can subtract the accumulated size of the currently allocated buffers from the total memory.

With OpenCL, you can assign callback calls to the buffers, which are called when the buffer is destroyed (`clSetMemObjectDestructorCallback`). So I use those to clean up when the buffer is released. Hint: the cl_mem parameter with which the callback is called is NOT a valid mem object. It may have already been destroyed so you cannot query it for its size (that took me a couple of hours, even though it's clearly stated in the standard ...).

This way, I can always know, how much memory is left on the device.

Comment: That's a good workaround. However, it is not possible to guarantee that the amount of memory you allocate is all that's used up on the device - but this estimate may be useful in some cases.

Comment: You mean that it's possible to allocate more than `CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE` returns? Yeah, I've made that experience too. Or do you mean the other way around? Of course, this only works if this application is the only one accessing the device.

Comment: No, I mean that CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE is what the OpenCL implementation can allocate. However, the amount that is actually used on the device may vary due to pixel format changes or cached data used by the implementation for performance. And yes, a video card plugged into a display will completely ruin this metric.